How to cancel the admin permission of a group?
I set a group called music, using the command groupadd -g 500 music.
Then I add alice to the music group, and set alice to be the admin of the music group, using these two commands gpasswd -a alice music and gpasswd -A alice music.
Now alice can add people to the music group without the foil of the denied permission, but how to cancel this permission? I checked the man page of the gpasswd but found nothing about option of canceling the admin permission. I try to reach the objective by removing alice away from group music, using command gpasswd -d alice music, but alice still have the permission to manipulate group member. How can I cancel the admin permission of a group?

You can set the administrators list to the empty list:
gpasswd -A '' music

which will revoke such privilege.
The actual storage of the administrators information is in the 3rd field of the entry in /etc/gshadow, the shadow side of /etc/group,  as described in gshadow(5):

Each line of this file contains the following colon-separated fields:
group name
[...]
encrypted password
[...]
administrators
It must be a comma-separated list of user names.
Administrators can change the password or the members of the    group.
Administrators also have the same permissions as the members    (see
below).
members
[...]

So the same could have been achieved by running:
vigr -s

(with -s selecting /etc/gshadow instead of /etc/group) and manually removing out alice in the 3rd field of the music entry. So from something like:
music:!:alice:

to:
music:!::

